# Deploy project failed on Vercel

Tags: deployment

I am unable to deploy my project following errors occur while deploying

unknown: Entry /opt/build/repo/index.html does not exist
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

[This is my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBW0h.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.